# Is there a way to use radio buttons in a Google Sheets Dialog and save the value, using Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, radio-button

My goal, simply put, is to highlight a cell range on one google sheet (the 'source') and move it to another, different google sheet document (the 'target').  The Target has multiple sheets(tabs?) and new ones are added often.

IMPORTANT: To be clear, I am NOT copying from one sheet to another sheet, in the same document. I am copying from one google sheet document, to a complexity different google sheet document.

Currently, I have code that allows users to:

1. Highlight a cell range in the SOURCE google sheet.
2. Select the custom menu option.
3. Upon selecting the custom menu option, the data in the highlighted cell range is copied to the TARGET google sheet.

Currently, the the "Target" is hardcoded.

What I want to do is to build a Radio Button list.  One Radio Button for every Sheet that exists in the TARGET google sheet.  Allow the user to choose one, then move the data to that specific Sheet, when they press the "OK" button.

I've searched for a while, but I'm unable to find anything about even putting radio buttons in a google sheets dialog, let alone build the radio button list based on sheets that exist in another google sheet document.

Comment: A dialog can handle any html/javascript/css you want to give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question, as I now know HTML needs to be used.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use the Google Sheets checkboxes with the below script to create a radio button effect (still looks like a checkbox, but when one checkbox in a given row is checked, it unchecks any other checkbox in that row (columns B-E) that had previously been checked).

My checkboxes are in columns B,C,D,E and I believe (I am learning as I go, so I'm not 100% sure) that is what "for(var i = 2;i<6;i++)" refers to, with Column B=2 and Column E=5 (i.e. <6).  In my testing, this meant that in any given row of my spreadsheet, if one checkbox is checked, any checkboxes in columns B-E would be unchecked.  This works perfectly for my purposes, as my only checkboxes are in columns B-E, but I did experiment and found that if I added a checkbox in column A, for example, it would cause checkboxes in B-E to be unchecked, but not vice-versa (i.e. checking a box in columns B-E did not uncheck the one in A).  This didn't matter for my purposes since I don't need checkboxes anywhere else, so I didn't troubleshoot it, but obviously some additional code would be needed if you don't want this to happen.

```
   function onEdit(evt) {

    var range = evt.range;
    var val = range.getValue();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var col = range.getColumn();

    // -------------------------------------
    // --- Only 1 checkbox per row can be ticked ---
    // -------------------------------------
  for(var i = 2;i<6;i++){
    if(i == col) continue;

        if (val) {
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,i).setValue('FALSE');    
}
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of a radio dialog:

```
function radiosOnADialog() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var html='<html><head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script></head>';
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><input type="radio" name="rgroup" id="%s" value="%s" onChange="getSelected();" />%s','id'+ Number(i+1),'radio' + Number(i+1),' radio' + Number(i+1));
  }
  html+='<body><br /><input type="button" value="close" onClick="google.script.host.close()" /><div id="msgdiv"></div>';
  html+='<script>function getSelected(){ var selected=document.querySelector(\'input[name="rgroup"]:checked\').value;document.getElementById("msgdiv").innerHTML="<br />You selected " + selected  + ".<br />";}</script></body></html>'; 
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'A Radio Dialog');
}
```

- [Radio Buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

The Dialog:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I was wondering if there was a way to do this with Google App Scripts and not using HTML.  It doesn't appear there.

Comment: While that function utilizes html strings it is infact a server side function.  There use to be another UI that created panels and other things.  Honestly, I never used because I'm more comfortable with html,css and javascript.

Comment: As far as I know all Google Sheets Dialog and Sidebars are clientside.  So html,javascript and css. And numerous other libraries like JQuery.

Comment: It's all good. I appreciate your help.  I'm a 100% novice at this stuff. Learning from scratch. I'll get there. Thank you, again!

Comment: I have a simple dialog that works within a spreadsheet that might be of some value to you.  You can read about and get the code for it [here](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript). It's called Copy/Move Dialog (Same Spreadsheet)