# Running a script inside HTML

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script

I am trying to run a script inside my HTML, building a table with data.  I have a range of values, and I only want this For Loop to run on the very last item in the range.  Here is the code I have started with.

```
  <? for(var i=0;i<rodsAmt.length;i++){ ?>
    <? if(i>=rodsAmt.length) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?= rodsAmt[i]; ?></td> 
          </tr> 
    <? } ?>      
  <? } ?>
```

Comment: You can build html inside of a Google Apps Script this way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680044/7215091

Comment: Heres one that builds an html table from data in a spreadsheet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56479763/7215091

Comment: Or learn about scriptlets in templated html here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Comment: Welcome. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're running into? Also what do you mean by 'I only want this For Loop to run on the very last item in the range? Check out Cooper's answer on this question on how to loop through an array and display it in HTML in GAS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204282

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed to do.

```
  <? for(var i=0;i<rodsAmt.length;i++){ ?>           
    <? if(i==rodsAmt.length-2) { ?>        
          <tr>              
            <td><?= rodsAmt[i]; ?></td> 
          </tr> 
    <? } ?>                
  <? } ?>
```

Comment: Or just `<tr>              
            <td><?= rodsAmt[rodsAmt.length-2]; ?></td> 
          </tr>` No loop.