# Can I create dynamic menu items using a form popup?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Would it be possible to use a popup form to handle parameters for a custom menu item in a spreadsheet?  I'm not necessarily asking for someone to write the script.  I just don't want to try only to discover I've been wasting my time.

In my spreadsheet, I want to be able to save a sheet to a new file/spreadsheet  (that part is done) and then access/load that saved sheet again later through a custom menu command.  The issue I'm running into is that I want to be able to call the same function every time, but be able to specify a parameter (which sheet to access).  My thought is that the form would act like an alert with multiple choices populated by the array of available sheets.

Or is there a simpler way to offer a multiple choice without going through a series of `YES/NO` alerts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use dialogs.

[modeless dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModelessDialog(Object,String))

[modal dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String))

[Dialog Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680044/7215091)

Comment: Thanks Cooper!  I immediately clicked the first two links and tried to figure things out. It wasn't until I saw your example that it all came together and made sense.  Thank you very much!